# Installing packages remotely via bash script in ubuntu

Tags: bash, scripts

I am trying to install firefox packages to all my linux hosts remotely using a bash script. But when ever i execute the script i get the following error. How do i enable DISPLAY in bash script?

#### Error:

```
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
No protocol specified
Error: cannot open display: :0.0
```

Comment: Can you specify what you use to install firefox? If you use `apt-get` it should work without any problem...

Comment: Can you provide the script? Also how do you execute it? Using SSH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is very odd: the error seems to be generated by firefox needing to access X functionalities (which is normal), but those `export` commands should be sufficient to make it work (if you have a running X session on the hosts).

The only tips I can give to you is to replace the export line like this (you should only need one):

```
#export DISPLAY=:0.0
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or try to explicitly set the display on each command:

```
su user1 -c 'DISPLAY=:0 firefox -no-remote -CreateProfile firefox18'
```

Answer (score 0):

On the machine you want the firefox to appear on try running the command xhost -, this allows client windows to connect from any host. Once you've done running firefox you should probably run xhost + to keep secure.